# I write two same queries in mysql but one return nothing and i cant diffrentiate among them.please help me

Tags: mysql

I have used this query for  my mysql datbase

```
SELECT DISTINCT(order_detail.id), product.product_name, product.image, order_detail.*
FROM order_detail,
     product,
     `order`
WHERE `order`.user_name = 'shuvranshu'
  AND order_detail.order_id = '11'
  AND `order_detail`.product_id = product.id
```

It gives me results.
But when I use the query..

```
SELECT DISTINCT(order_detail.id), product.product_name, product.image, order_detail.*
FROM order_detail,
     product,
     `order`
WHERE `order`.user_name = 'shuvranshue'
  AND order_detail.order_id = '11'
  AND `order_detail`.product_id = product.id
```

This query return nothing.
I can't find the difference between these two queries.but they results different.

Comment: Maybe the user in the second query (order.user_name='shuvranshue') doesn't exist.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function. Let's start over. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

In the first one you have 'shuvranshu' and in the second one you have 'shuvranshue'. You have 'e' in the end.

Comment: I thought this should be a comment not an answer. That's why I had already answered in a comment :)